# value change listener is not working without submit() JSF

Tags: jsf, valuechangelistener

Here is my JSP:

```
  <h:panelGrid columns="2">

Selected Location : 
    <h:inputText id="emp" value="#{employee.locationCode}" size="20" />

    Select a country {method binding}: 
    <h:selectOneMenu id="empl" value="#{employee.locationCode}" 
        valueChangeListener="#{employee.countryLocationCodeChanged}" onchange="submit()">
        <f:selectItems value="#{employee.locationInMap}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
  </h:panelGrid>
```

My bean:
    private static Map locationMap;
    private String locationCode = "en"; //default value

```
static{
    locationMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    locationMap.put("United Kingdom", "en"); //label, value
    locationMap.put("French", "fr");
    locationMap.put("German", "de");
    locationMap.put("China", "zh_CN");
    }
public void countryLocationCodeChanged(ValueChangeEvent e){
    //assign new value to localeCode
    setLocationCode(e.getNewValue().toString());

}

public Map<String,String> getLocationInMap() {
    return this.locationMap;
}

public String getLocationCode() {
    return locationCode;
}

public void setLocationCode(String locationCode) {
    this.locationCode = locationCode;
}
public void changeEvent(String locationCode) {
    this.locationCode = locationCode;
}
```

Apart form this i have lot more fields in jsp. Its giving illegal argument exception when i am selecting drop down values. I guess submit() is making some issues.. can anybody help. Thanks in advance..

Comment: This might be a problem, I'm not sure if it pertains to the question. However, your field's name locationMap and the getter is locationInMap. Try to keep these the same names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your selectItems tag.

```
<f:selectItems value="#{employee.locationInMap}" />
```

You cann't intialize entire map to **selectOneMenu** tag.

just try with **entryset** as below:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.locationInMap.entrySet()}" var="entry" 
itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}" />
```

You can find more information on selectOneMenu [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

Comment: Im getting this exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /EmployeeJSFPage/addEmployee.jsp(246,6) Attribute var invalid for tag selectItems according to TLD